# MySQL: get oldest record from most recent group

Tags: mysql, records

Sorry for the confusing title, but it's the best way to explain it. This is not a usual "most recent from group" problem and I haven't been able to find anything similar on the web.

I have a status table that tracks what people are doing at various work sites. It contains records that link people, status and location.

```
ID, start_date, person_ID, location_ID, status
1,  2014-10-12, 1,         1,           job a
2,  2014-10-13, 2,         2,           job b
3,  2014-10-15, 1,         3,           job c
4,  2014-10-21, 1,         3,           job d
5,  2014-10-22, 2,         4,           job a
6,  2014-10-26, 2,         2,           job d
```

I need to be able to determine how long each person as been at the current site - I'm hoping to get results like this:

```
person_ID, location_ID, since
1,         3,           2014-10-15
2,         2,           2014-10-26
```

Getting when they started the current job is relatively easy by joining the max(start_date), but I need the min(start_date) from the jobs done at the most recent location.

I have been trying to join the min(start_date) within the records that match the current location (from the most recent record), and that works great until I have a person (like person 2) who has multiple visits to the current location... you can see in my desired results that I want the 10-26 date, not the 10-13 which is the first time they were at the site.

I need some method for matching the the job records for a given person, and then iterating back until the location doesn't match. I'm figuring there has to be some way to do this with some sub-queries and some clever joins, but I haven't been able to find it yet, so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: So why 2014-10-15 for person with id 1 instead of 2014-10-21

Comment: Because they arrived at site 3 on 2014-10-15, and stayed there to start job d on 2014-10-21. The query is for accommodation of our service techs, so I need to know when they arrived at the site regardless of jobs being completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you could use `EXISTS` to eliminate all but the most recent locations per person, and get the min date from the resulting rows.

```
SELECT person_id, location_id, MIN(start_date) since
FROM status s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM status 
  WHERE s.person_id = person_id 
    AND s.location_id <> location_id
    AND s.start_date < start_date)
GROUP BY person_id
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69001d/1).

Basically, it *eliminates all locations and times where the same person has visited another location more recently*. For example;

```
1,  2014-10-12, 1,         1,           job a
```

...is eliminated since person 1 has visited location 3 more recently, while;

```
3,  2014-10-15, 1,         3,           job c
```

...is kept since the same person has only visited the same location more recently.

It then just picks the least recent time per person. Since only the rows from the last location are kept, it will be the least recent time from the most recent location.

Comment: Amazingly.. this seems to work - but I'm not sure why. How does the not exists eliminate someone going to a site, going to another site and then back again? In my example table above for person 2, wouldn't the not exists return row 2 and 6 and then return the date from row 2 (being the min)?

Comment: I can't break this.. so I think you have it sir. Like I said above, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how it does it, so I can put in to prod with confidence. I can see that your subquery is finding all the eliminating all the other locations (same person different site).. so I guess the s.start_date < start_date is including the "previous visit" records in the sub query set, but I can't really understand how.

Comment: @whiteatom I made an attempt at a quick explanation, let me know if it's to unclear and I'll update it when I have a bit more time :)

Comment: Yup.. perfect.. I now see what's going on.. and it has a very small performance hit.. You sir are a SQL god among men.

Comment: Ok, one more caveat. In my simplification of the problem, I eliminated the future records from the sample data. I currently have future records in the same table that make up the scheduling. I have solved it by adding another sub-select for past records in the from clause, but that seems like it could be done more cleanly.

Comment: Actually I solved this too. For future readers.. Put the 3 conditions of the where in brackets and add "and start_date <= current_date()"

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is with variables to keep track of the information you need:

```
select person_id, location_id, min(start_date) as since
from (select s.*,
             (@rn := if(@p <> person_id, if(@p:=person_id, 1, 1),
                        if(@l = location_id, @rn,
                           if(@l:=location_d, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                          )
                        )
             ) as location_counter
      from status s cross join
           (select @p := 0, @l := 0, @rn := 0) vars
      order by person_id, start_date desc
     ) s
where location_counter = 1
group by person_id, location_id;
```

The weird logic with the variables is (trying to) enumerate the locations for each person.  It should be incrementing `@rn` only when the location changes and resetting the value to `1` for a new person.

Answer (score -1):

Quite simple actually.

```
SELECT g.person_ID,
  (SELECT l.location_ID
   FROM status l
   WHERE l.person_ID = g.person_ID
   AND l.start_date = MAX(g.start_date)) AS location,
  MAX(g.start_date) AS since
FROM status g
GROUP BY g.person_ID
```

This uses a grouping on person_ID, and uses a SELECT for the location column expression.

The sole question is whether you meant MIN i.o. MAX as in your example you yield the youngest date, not the oldest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this isn't want I need. You are suggesting a "max per group" solution. I need the date they arrived at the current location - if the most recent rows all have the same location, I need the first of the current "cluster" of rows.